# Relationship between two taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

for a project, I've a CPT products with two taxonomies : category and brand.

I would like to build a navigation from a category to a product under a brand.

- page 1 : list the categories terms
- page 2 : list the brand term having the selected category term
- page 3 : list the products under the brand and the category
- page 4 : display the product

Obviously, page 1 and 4 are easy to do but i can't figure out how to retrieve the terms in the page 2 and the products in the page 3.

I'm sure there is a way to do that. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Cyril

Answer (score 0):

As per the post linked to below you can use URL parameters to do the "page 3" part:

```
    www.example.com/post-type/?taxonomy_y=term_y&taxonomy_x=term_x
```

WordPress will automatically filter the posts to include only those posts tagged with term_y in taxonomy_y and term_x in taxonomy_x.

http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

To do the "page 2" part perform a custom query instead of using the URL parameter method above and then loop through the query results and build your list of "brand terms that have the selected category terms".

```
    query_posts(array(
      'brand' => 123,
      'category' => 456,
    ) );
```

http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/